# Javascript loop through date/times in vali increments

Tags: javascript, date

I've trying to build out a table from a start time until the end of day in defined increments.

eg: if the user selects 15 minute increment starting from 8:10am, the times goes
8:10,8:25,8:40,8:55,9:10...

My current code does not correct work out we've changed to the next hour and then start the offset again, eg i get:
815,830,845,905,935,1025,1125,1225,1325...

Here is a JSFiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/inboxdesign/c8f2dhng/13/

Here is the code I have so far;

```
// from select:
let $first_hour = 8;
let $first_minute = 10;
let day_count = 1;  // don't worry about this;

let duration = 15; // increment

        var offset = 0;
        var current_time = parseInt($first_hour + $first_minute);
        for (var i = 0; i < 120; i++) {
            if (current_time < 2400) {
                var time_string = ('' + current_time);
                var time_minutes = parseInt(time_string.substring(time_string.length - 2));
                if (time_minutes < 60) {
                    // offset = 0;
                    times += '<tr>';
                    for (var d = 1; d <= day_count; d++) {
                        times += '<td>d: ' + d + ' : time: ' + current_time + ' ->' + time_string.substring(time_string.length - 2) + ' offset: ' + offset +'</td>';
                    }
                    times += '</tr>';
                } else {
                    offset = (time_minutes - 60);
                    // times += '<tr>';
                    // times += '<td>o:' + offset + ' tm: ' + time_minutes + '</td>';
                    // time_minutes = offset;
                    // times += '</td>';
                }
            }
            console.log('current_time: ' + current_time);
            current_time = parseInt(current_time + duration + offset);
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: sorry - if you click the fiddle link, the times go:

815,830,845,905,935,1025,1125,1225,1325...
It's not resetting times that overlap hours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line your else offset has to be reset to 0

```
for (var d = 1; d <= SP.new_conference.day_count; d++) {
                        times += '<td>d: ' + d + ' : time: ' + current_time + ' ->' + time_minutes + ' offset: ' + offset +'</td>';
                    }
                //  times += '</tr>';
                } else {
                    offset = 0;
```

and then your current time and offset should look like this

```
current_time = parseInt(current_time + SP.new_conference.duration );
      offset+=SP.new_conference.duration
```

I have fixed this issues in the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sven07/uakgLmfq/) if you want to have a look